# Test.StopTest Not Resetting Limits?

Tags: unit-test, governorlimits

I have a test running in API Version 29. I am actively testing against governor limits and I think I am running into a bug. My test has the following sequence:

```
//setup

Test.startTest();
    // update some records
Test.stopTest();

system.assert(false, Limits.getQueries());
```

And the yield is:

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: 100
```

Isn't `Test.stopTest` supposed to reset governor limits?

Comment: Perhaps your limits were already at 100 from the prior stuff you did before Test.startTest()

Comment: `Test.startTest` should also clear out governor limits AFAIK.

Comment: Try adding a couple random queries in before that assert and see what happens?  Or did you already try that?  Like after the stopTest()

Comment: You have one set of limits for the setup and one set for inside the Test.startTest() method. You can't just reset them. What you are doing is switching to the original limits.

Comment: You will get another set of limits for the next Test.startTest() block, but you don't get a new set for outside (in the same execution context, as far as I know)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Test.stopTest resets back you to the governor limits of immediately before you called Test.startTest(), *not* back to all zeroes. Your total test time outside of startTest() and stopTest() is not doubled if you use that pattern. Within the Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() area, you get a new set of limits, based on what you do first. You only get one start-stop pair per method. Each test method gets its own set of governor limits.